# Best structure Codeigniter, constant top menu

Tags: php, codeigniter, templates, navigation

Maybe a HMVC structure would have been best when I look back.

I load the following views in every controller.

```
$this->load->view('header');
$this->load->view('DEPENDING');
$this->load->view('header');
```

In my header-view I have a menu which I show *Home | Inbox | Contact* us and so on. Now I want to load how many new messages you have like this *Home | Inbox **(4)** | Contact*. If Im not wrong the 4 most be loaded thorugh a query every time. Which I then need to include a call to a model in EVERY controller. Like e.g.

```
$inbox['new_messages'] = $this->Call_the_model->get_new_messages(); // user id go through session

$this->load->view('header', $inbox);
$this->load->view('DEPENDING');
$this->load->view('header');
```

Am I right? Is there simple solution for me to use - even if Im not using HMVC?

Comment: Look into **[extending a base controller](http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2010/02/CodeIgniter-Base-Classes-Keeping-it-DRY)**. You could then create a function in your base controller to call the 3 views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the ideas is -

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/core_classes.html

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        //load your model
        $inbox_new_messages = $this->Call_the_model->get_new_messages();
        //save in session
        $this->session->set_userdata('sess_inbox_new_messages', $inbox_new_messages);
    }

}
```

then just extend your controllers with new MY_Controllers and

```
class Welcome extends MY_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

 }
```

in your view files - check if that session variable is set and display the number.
Hope that helps.

Comment: Why save it to the session? If you set the variable as `$this->inbox_new_messages` in the construct you will be able to access it in any controller that extends the MY_Controller.

Comment: well - as I said its one of the ideas to achieve what's required. Choose what you prefer. :)